# r nested glm with two subgroups

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, glm

I am trying to run a simple glm model like this.

```
         library(dplyr)
         library(purrr)
         library(tidyr)
         library(broom)

         data("mtcars")
         head(mtcars)
         
         mtcars$Name <- row.names(mtcars)
         row.names(mtcars) <- NULL

         glm(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars)
```

No issues so far.

Next I am trying to run this model on every subgroup of `gear` i.e `gear=3, gear=4, gear=5` so I am running my glm model within a dlply function like this.

```
Model1 <- plyr::dlply(mtcars, "gear",
            function(x)
              tryCatch(
                glm(mpg ~ wt,
                    data =x ),
                error = function(e) NA), .drop = TRUE)

SummaryCars <- map2_df(Model1,
                        names(Model1),
                          ~broom::tidy(.x, confint = TRUE)[2,] %>%
                              mutate(gear = .y))
```

Now I have a third subgroup `carb`. This variable has 6 levels

```
table(mtcars$carb)

1  2  3  4  6  8 
7 10  3 10  1  1
```

Exclude carb levels 6 and 8. I like to run my model on `carb` levels 1,2,3,&4. For each level of `gear`. But I like to exclude one level of carb during each iteration.

**Model1** - Carb Level 1,2,3 (***Exclude data from carb= 4***)

````
 ```
 Model1 <- plyr::dlply(mtcars, "gear",
        function(x)
          tryCatch(
            glm(mpg ~ wt,
                data =x ),
            error = function(e) NA), .drop = TRUE)

  SummaryCars <- map2_df(Model1,
                    names(Model1),
                      ~broom::tidy(.x, confint = TRUE)[2,] %>%
                          mutate(gear = .y))
   ```
````

**Model2 ** - Carb Level 1,2,4 (***Exclude data from carb= 3***)

````
 ```
 Model1 <- plyr::dlply(mtcars, "gear",
        function(x)
          tryCatch(
            glm(mpg ~ wt,
                data =x ),
            error = function(e) NA), .drop = TRUE)

  SummaryCars <- map2_df(Model1,
                    names(Model1),
                      ~broom::tidy(.x, confint = TRUE)[2,] %>%
                          mutate(gear = .y))
   ```
````

**Model3 ** - Carb Level 1,3,4 (***Exclude data from carb= 2***)

````
 ```
 Model1 <- plyr::dlply(mtcars, "gear",
        function(x)
          tryCatch(
            glm(mpg ~ wt,
                data =x ),
            error = function(e) NA), .drop = TRUE)

  SummaryCars <- map2_df(Model1,
                    names(Model1),
                      ~broom::tidy(.x, confint = TRUE)[2,] %>%
                          mutate(gear = .y))
   ```
````

**Mode4l ** - Carb Level 2,3,4 (***Exclude data from carb= 1***)

````
 ```
 Model1 <- plyr::dlply(mtcars, "gear",
        function(x)
          tryCatch(
            glm(mpg ~ wt,
                data =x ),
            error = function(e) NA), .drop = TRUE)

  SummaryCars <- map2_df(Model1,
                    names(Model1),
                      ~broom::tidy(.x, confint = TRUE)[2,] %>%
                          mutate(gear = .y))
   ```
````

As you can see I can run the model within each levels of Gear (3,4,5) but I am not sure how to add another loop on top of this where data from one level is exclude and rest are considered.

Expected Final Results

```
         Model            SubModel     Estimate    Lower(CI)      Upper(CI)    stdError   p
         Exclude carb= 4  Gear = 3     xxx         xxxx           xxxx         xxx        x
         Exclude carb= 4  Gear = 4     xxx         xxxx           xxxx         xxx        x
         Exclude carb= 4  Gear = 5     xxx         xxxx           xxxx         xxx        x

         Exclude carb= 3  Gear = 3     xxx         xxxx           xxxx         xxx        x
         Exclude carb= 3  Gear = 4     xxx         xxxx           xxxx         xxx        x
         Exclude carb= 3  Gear = 5     xxx         xxxx           xxxx         xxx        x

         Exclude carb= 2  Gear = 3     xxx         xxxx           xxxx         xxx        x
         Exclude carb= 2  Gear = 4     xxx         xxxx           xxxx         xxx        x
         Exclude carb= 2  Gear = 5     xxx         xxxx           xxxx         xxx        x

         Exclude carb= 1  Gear = 3     xxx         xxxx           xxxx         xxx        x
         Exclude carb= 1  Gear = 4     xxx         xxxx           xxxx         xxx        x
         Exclude carb= 1  Gear = 5     xxx         xxxx           xxxx         xxx        x
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I have included the code in my question showing what I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses nested `purrr::map_dfr()` calls around `broom::tidy(lm())`.

*Edit:* OP asked for a solution that handles subsets with no valid data. I now do that by wrapping the `tidy(lm())` call in [`purrr::possibly()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/safely.html). The output will include a single row of `NA` model parameters for invalid models.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)

# rmv carb == 6 or 8, add test case with all missing data, then split by gear
mtc_gears <- filter(mtcars, carb <= 4) %>% 
  mutate(wt = if_else(gear == 4 & carb != 4, NA_real_, wt))
mtc_gears <- split(mtc_gears, mtc_gears$gear)

safe_tidy_lm <- possibly(
  function(formula, data) tidy(lm(formula, data = data), conf.int = TRUE),
  tibble(.rows = 1)
)

map_dfr(
  1:4, 
  \(carb_drop) map_dfr(
      mtc_gears, 
      \(mtc_gear) safe_tidy_lm(
        mpg ~ wt, 
        data = filter(mtc_gear, carb != carb_drop)
      ), 
      .id = "Gear"
    ), 
  .id = "Exclude Carb"
)
```

```
#> Warning in qt(a, object$df.residual): NaNs produced
#> Warning in qt(a, object$df.residual): NaNs produced
#> # A tibble: 23 × 9
#>    `Exclude Carb` Gear  term     estim…¹ std.e…² stati…³ p.value conf.…⁴ conf.…⁵
#>    <chr>          <chr> <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 1              3     (Interc…   25.1    3.51     7.14 3.15e-5   17.2   32.9  
#>  2 1              3     wt         -2.44   0.842   -2.90 1.59e-2   -4.32  -0.563
#>  3 1              4     (Interc…   30.2    3.61     8.37 1.40e-2   14.7   45.7  
#>  4 1              4     wt         -3.38   1.16    -2.92 1.00e-1   -8.37   1.61 
#>  5 1              5     (Interc…   44.4    1.82    24.3  2.62e-2   21.2   67.5  
#>  6 1              5     wt         -8.92   0.769  -11.6  5.47e-2  -18.7    0.846
#>  7 2              3     (Interc…   28.9    3.01     9.58 5.11e-6   22.1   35.7  
#>  8 2              3     wt         -3.28   0.733   -4.47 1.55e-3   -4.93  -1.62 
#>  9 2              4     (Interc…   30.2    3.61     8.37 1.40e-2   14.7   45.7  
#> 10 2              4     wt         -3.38   1.16    -2.92 1.00e-1   -8.37   1.61 
#> # … with 13 more rows, and abbreviated variable names ¹​estimate, ²​std.error,
#> #   ³​statistic, ⁴​conf.low, ⁵​conf.high
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: this works for the toy dataset perfectly. However if there are some levels with NA or no data for some subgroups then the code does not work. I am calling my glm inside the `trycatch` function to exclude subgroups that dont have any data  `tryCatch(
            glm(mpg ~ wt,
                data =x ),
            error = function(e) NA), .drop = TRUE)`  but I am not sure how to implement similar error handling mechanism into your solution.

Comment: Hi Zephryl, the solution works for `lm` type of models. I am wondering what changes needs to be done if I were to implement this on a geeglm type of dataset , that takes parameters like, `family = gaussain(link = "identity"), id = id, constr = "independence"`, my apologies if this is a separate question.

Comment: @EagleHawk Try tinkering with `safe_tidy_lm()`, specifically replacing the `lm()` call with `geeglm()` and adding your parameters. Any parameters you want to pass as arguments can be added to the function definition. If you need to pass more than one parameter per iteration, you can look at [`map()` variants](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html) like `map2_dfr()` or `pmap_dfr()`, or by adding another layer of nested `map_dfr()`. For anything beyond that, I'd suggest asking a new question.

Comment: Hi zephryl what is ` \(carb_drop) ` I have never seen a syntax like this before ?

Comment: That’s R’s anonymous function shorthand. `\(carb_drop)` is equivalent to `function(carb_drop)`.

Comment: thanks I never seen that before, I am learning many new things.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
mtcars %>%
  filter(!carb %in% c(6,8))%>%
  mutate(Exclude = list(sort(unique(carb))))%>%
  group_by(gear)%>%
  summarise(.groups = 'drop',
            Exclude = Exclude[[1]],
            result = map(Exclude, 
                  ~tidy(glm(mpg~wt, data = cur_data(), subset = carb!=.x))))%>%
  unnest(result)
# A tibble: 24 × 7
    gear Exclude term        estimate std.e…¹ stati…² p.value
   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     3       1 (Intercept)    25.1    3.51     7.14 3.15e-5
 2     3       1 wt             -2.44   0.842   -2.90 1.59e-2
 3     3       2 (Intercept)    28.9    3.01     9.58 5.11e-6
 4     3       2 wt             -3.28   0.733   -4.47 1.55e-3
 5     3       3 (Intercept)    28.4    3.15     9.04 3.96e-6
 6     3       3 wt             -3.18   0.786   -4.04 2.36e-3
 7     3       4 (Intercept)    29.8    5.18     5.76 4.25e-4
 8     3       4 wt             -3.43   1.47    -2.33 4.82e-2
 9     4       1 (Intercept)    37.8    4.39     8.61 1.35e-4
10     4       1 wt             -5.37   1.49    -3.60 1.14e-2
# … with 14 more rows, and abbreviated variable names
#   ¹​std.error, ²​statistic
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: same as I mentioned to zephryl, your code works perfectly on this toy datataset but if there are any subgroups that have no data (NA) then this code fails. I have used the `trycatch` function in my code previously to handle these situations but I am not sure how to include that `trycatch` type error handling  if there are no data for some some subgroups.

Comment: @EagleHawk use an if else before runing the tidy part. ie `if(nrow(na.omit(filter(cur_data(),  carb!=.x)))>2) glm(mpg~wt, data = cur_data(), subset = carb!=.x) else NA`

Comment: I am getting few errors. This is how I implemented your solutions,  `
mtcars %>%
  filter(!carb %in% c(6,8))%>%
  mutate(Exclude = list(sort(unique(carb))))%>%
  group_by(gear)%>%
  dplyr::summarise(.groups = 'drop',
            Exclude = Exclude[[1]],
            result = map(Exclude, 
  if(nrow(na.omit(filter(cur_data(),  carb!=.x)))>2)
                  ~tidy(glm(mpg~wt, data = cur_data(), subset = carb!=.x)) else NA))%>%
  unnest(result) `